# 32-bit compatability environment in Linux Mint 19?

Tags: linux, 64bit, 32bit

I am trying to run Secondlife in Linux Mint 19. However it's a 32-bit program and I'm running a 64-bit system. How do I install a 32-bit compatibility environment in Linux Mint 19?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386

apt-get update

apt-get install multiarch-support

apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

If your app require more libraries, install everyone with :i386 at the library name.

Ubuntu packages website can help you to found out, the packages providing files, that eventually are missing.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and the advice about multiarch-support not needed anymore.

Comment: thanks for the help. None of the code worked.I encoutnered an error when trying to run the first line (dpkg etc.) with dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/arch-new': Permission denied
  I tried running it with sudo and nothing happened. I will check the website

Comment: It will not return nothing, just run it , and try again to execute your application at end. Showing the errors for us.

Comment: It seems to be a connection error. Which doesn't make sense because my connection is robust (I'm on a University's network that allows secondlife This is the error: 2019-01-08T05:16:33Z WARNING: LLViewerMediaImpl::navigateInternal: Couldn't navigate to: http://viewer-login.agni.lindenlab.com/?channel=Second%20Life%20Release&firstlogin=TRUE&grid=Agni&lang=en&login_content_version=2&os=Linux%204.15&sourceid=&version=5.0.9%20(329906) as there is no media type for: text/html

Comment: 2019-01-08T05:18:51Z WARNING: stageAfterCompletion: HTTP request 0xf392d410 failed after 5 retries.  Reason:  Couldn't connect to server (Easy_7)
2019-01-08T05:18:51Z WARNING: onCompleted: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Error[Easy_7] cannot access url 'https://sim10730.agni.lindenlab.com:12043/cap/2999b8b3-195c-2977-0ae9-d84888f29e22' because Couldn't connect to server
------------------------------------------------------------
2019-01-08T05:18:51Z WARNING: requestBaseCapabilitiesCoro: Received capabilities for region that no longer exists!

Comment: And if you wget to that address what happen ?

Comment: I should be able to actually log in to the account.

Comment: I haven't seen any other error images in the terminal

Comment: Well but the port is listening in  for wget?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, port?

Comment: I see that the address are using port 12043, now you know what i am talking about? Maybe you have some kind of firewall blocking connection to this port or missing ssl libraries for 32 bits.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it. Perhaps there's something wrong with the connection?

Comment: Yes. Maybe your firewall are blocking connections to this port. If I am not wrong mint comes with a firewall pre-configured. You need to disable or configure it.